# How to use WHERE with UPDATE

Tags: sql, oracle

When I use this query it works fine:

```
SELECT
FIO,
UNS,
CSTATUS,
SSTATUS
FROM U_STUDENT
WHERE UNS = '19398045';
```

but when I'm trying to modify the table with similar usage of WHERE:

```
UPDATE U_STUDENT
SET CSTATUS = '000100000000104Ah',
    SSTATUS = 'Status name'
WHERE UNS = '19398045';
```

I'm getting an error:

[image]

```
Error: Expected  ";" (row.4, col.1 in INPUT)
WHERE UNS = '19398045';
         ^
```

I'm tried to check documentation and couldn't find why that might be wrong, I wonder what might cause the issue

Comment: I can not reproduce the error here: https://sqlize.online/s/kf Do you post all SQL code? It's looks as your UI tool error, not SQL

Comment: The SQL statement is correct. Please check if you are executing againt wrong DB

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev yes, code is full, it looks like database don't understand WHERE keyword when I use UPDATE.

Comment: @PapinGreshnikAda Your code works [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/A28NPWIY). We cannot replicate the error you are getting.

Comment: Check if you have any special characters which is not visible

Comment: Retype the SQL from scratch, without copy-paste. Just be sure it isn't a hidden byte in there.

Answer (score 0):

in your table you have this data UNS = '19398045', problem is not about this. check here: CSTATUS = '000100000000104Ah',
SSTATUS = 'Status name'

maybe type is not true(varchar,number) or length is too much.